# Tensorflow - Visualizing learned filters of a pretrained network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, visualization, tensorboard

I'm currently trying to visualize the learned filters of my CNN with tensorflow in python.
I found many versions working with the mnist dataset while training a new network, but wasn't able to apply it to my application.
I trained an Estimator object, which is stored on my disk, with a custom dataset. The model contains layers such as

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

and only want to visialize a prediction on a single picture with dimensions (28,28,3).
In tensorboard, this layer is simply called "conv2d", while the others are called "conv2d_2" and so on, it basically has the same structure as the default MNIST network, except it's using the sigmoid function.

I don't know how to implement this - I thought about getting the weights and biases and recomputing every single layer in respect to stride and filter size, but I'm already failing at getting the weights and I think there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great job with the question - it's pretty nice to see such a polished question from a first-time asker. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm currently trying to visualize the learned filters of my CNN with tensorflow in python.

I think what you mean is visualizing the activations of a specific layer ? If so, you just need to run the tensor of this layer for the image you want like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Model definition
...
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
...

# Getting activations
acts = sess.run(conv1, {input_layer: your_image})

# Visualizing every filters
for i in range(acts.shape[3]):
  plt.imshow(acts[:,:,:,i].squeeze())
  plt.show()
```

If you are using Estimator, you can directly visualize the evolution of your activations using tf.summary.image() in your model_fn:

```
# In model_fn
...
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
acts_filters = tf.unstack(conv1, axis=3)
for i, filter in enumerate(acts_filters):
    tf.summary.image('filter' + str(i), tf.expand_dims(filter, axis=3))
```

Comment: Thanks, but where/how can I import my model itself, with the trained weights? When using my network, I usually used the line
    `estim = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model..., model_dir="...")`
before specifing that I want to predict something, for example

Comment: I'm sorry for asking again, but I don't know how to further work with the tf.summary.image. I added your second block of code to my model and it terminates without errors, but I don't know how to get anything from those tensors, and Google wasn't able to help me. Thank you for your patience

Comment: You just need to run a tensorboard using, for example, this command : tensorboard --logdir ./
And go to the image tab.

Comment: I don't seem to have an image tab, because I may have to add the summary.images to a writer or something like that, but again, I wasn't able to implement any of the found results on the problem. Tensorflow only shows scalars, graphs and projector. When I click "images" in the dropdown menu on the right, it says there are no images because I might have forgotten to write them to the event file, or maybe it can't find my event files.

Comment: Estimator adds any summary to the event file automatically. Did you try training once again ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Training for a few steps did the trick. It somehow didn't create a prediction before, so it may only work for training.